# How to get that good smell to stick around [shampoo, cologne]

Tags: personal-care, smell

How do I keep my cologne smell to stay on me? It always seems to leave with the wind, and I want it to smell for a while. I even resorted to parfum, but it doesn't last much longer. On a (somewhat?) related topic, how do I keep my shampoo smell to stay in my hair?

Answer (score 5):

Invest in a small spray bottle that you can carry in your pocket or backpack, filled with some of your cologne. Spray as necessary, but be aware you grow accustomed to your smell and therefore it may seem more weak when it is in fact strong to others around you.

Shampoo smell is dependent on how long your hair is, but others should not be able to smell it when a decent distance away from you.

Comment: +1 for 'grow accustomed'. Some people seem to be totally unaware that they smell like they fell over the counter at the chemists & broke half the bottles :/

Comment: Yeah, but I go through cologne quick. I would rather have a method. But thanks!